# File upload in asp.net mvc using ajax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax

I have a simple html form with two controls:

**input-text** and **input-file**

I need to write an ajax query (using jquery is better) to send data (file and value from text field to mvc acton)

I wrote

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/controller/acton",
    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
    data: 'text=' + $("#text").val() + '&file=' + $("#file").val()
...
```

and in controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult StoreItem(FormCollection forms)
  {
     foreach (string inputTagName in Request.Files)
  ...
```

this returns null in Request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't POST a file using only javascript.

Look at http://www.uploadify.com/ or something like http://www.swfupload.org/

Answer (score 2):

http://www.plupload.com is awesome

Comment: I was going to post this but I couldn't remember the name. +1